# Xorg 100% CPU usage and some lag in Thunderbird and LibreOffice

Tags: nvidia, xubuntu, xorg, libreoffice, thunderbird

Scrolling within a message in Thunderbird 78.7.1 is very slow. I've noticed that Xorg's CPU utilization is at 100% during scrolling. The Xorg version is 1:7.7+19ubuntu14. I suspect that the backend Thunderbird uses to display the message is not set up correctly, but I have no idea how could I go further to debug it and hopefully solve the problem. Thunderbird was installed through apt, in a Xubuntu 20.04.2 LTS distro, I am really disappointed, that such a performance issue could creep in into the LTS repo.  I hope you could give my ideas, or point me to useful solutions of similar problems.

No entry was written into `Xorg.0.log`.

Update: I have also noticed some delay in LibreOffice Writer and Calc, and the scrolling issue in Thunderbird does not appear in text messages, but in graphic heavy mails. I've looked at general Xorg troubleshooting, but I have not found anything suspicious.

I do not expect any right off the bat solution, but I would appreciate any hints, or guides how to troubleshoot it further. If there is a better site to ask such a question, please let me know.

Comment: On my very old laptop, Thunderbird is scrolling well in version 78.7.1 - I guess I'm going to have to suggest that there is some error further inside your system than Thunderbird.

Comment: Yes. I was sure, that the cause is in package, what the programs rely on. Though I have no idea how to fix this. Of course I could start out a new distro with a different window manager, but I've chosen XFCE for a reason. It is clean, simple and I feel comfortable using it.

Comment: LibreCalc has become unusable.  I've taken to ipython import pandas as pd.read_csv to get work done.